# Dynamic UITableView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Good day fellow coders,

**I'm building an app whereby I would like to display the closest shops to the user.**

However, this requires the TableView setup to be done after the view has loaded and appeared - hence after the user has granted location permission.

Is this possible to do this? If so where do I define the TableView protocol functions like "cellsForRowAt" and "numberOfRowsInSection" because these parameters are only available once I have 1) got permission for the location and 2) filtered the closest shops?

I hope the question is clear, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your data source (for the table) will have zero items until after the user has given you permission to access their location. The tableView can handle zero items just fine. When you are allowed to populate your data source, just reload the table.

Comment: @Magnas is right. And if you want to load your table only once then just assign your tableView Delegate and dataSource in you didUpdateLocation Method. So once you get permission and your location start updating only in this case your table view will load your data.
I Belive you can understand my wordings. Hope it will help you

Comment: Thank you, both answers make so much sense. Where do I put the following  "tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell")" , "tableView.delegate = self" and "tableView.dataSource = self" functions?? Can I put them in viewDidLoad?

Comment: @Lyndon2309 you can call this method is viewDidLoad()

Comment: @MohindraBhati and Magnas?

Comment: @GulfamKhan all three statements?

Comment: yes all three, its better to create a method called setupTableView() put these statements in that method and call it in viewDidLoad this way your code will be more structured and viewDidLoad() will be cleaner

Comment: @MohindraBhati when I define the protocol functions in the didUpdateLocations Method, the class returns an error asking me to add the protocols. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @MohindraBhati please assist me with the suggestion, I would like to implement it the way you suggested but I'm not sure how to get rid of the error above.

Comment: @Lyndon2309 You have to put 
"tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MainTableViewCell")" , "tableView.delegate = self" 
"tableView.dataSource = self"
 in your
optional func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, 
           didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])

You must implement this protocol method in your viewController Class. It will provide you with the callback whenever new location data is available.

And above method calls only if the user gives location permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when user done with 1) got permission for the location and 2) filtered the closest shops these 2 things just call tableview.reloadData() and your tableview will be refresh & updated with latest data.